# How to draw the below chart using highchart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Please help me with how can we draw the below chart using highchart.

Comment: You can explore scatter plot to achieve this in highcharts, or go for d3js if you are doing custom chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am almost sure that I already answered this question here, but I cannot find it.

Anyway - to split the chart use the `yAxis and xAxis plotLines` which position you can calculate dynamically in the `load` callback.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load() {
        const chart = this,
          yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
          xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];

        xAxis.addPlotLine({
          value: (xAxis.max + xAxis.min) / 2,
          color: 'grey',
          width: 2,
          dashStyle: 'dash'
        });

        yAxis.addPlotLine({
          value: (yAxis.max + yAxis.min) / 2,
          color: 'grey',
          width: 2,
          dashStyle: 'dash'
        });
      }
    }
  },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5xL7o1kg/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#addPlotLine

---

To color, the part of the split area use the `polygon` series type.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7smLnqad/

```
chart.addSeries({
  type: 'polygon',
  data: [
    [xAxis.min, yAxis.min],
    [(xAxis.max + xAxis.min) / 2, yAxis.min],
    [(xAxis.max + xAxis.min) / 2, (yAxis.max + yAxis.min) / 2],
    [xAxis.min, (yAxis.max + yAxis.min) / 2],
  ],
  color: 'rgba(244, 198, 245, 0.5)',
  showInLegend: false,
  enableMouseTracking: false,
})
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries

Comment: Thanks, a lot Sebastian for the quick reply 
As per your example(https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7smLnqad/), the graph has a line chart in a series. whereas I am looking for each dot in series and I will implement multiple series.

Comment: Use the scatter series type instead of the line - https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ux7mjbp0/

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sebastian for the quick response As per your example ( jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ux7mjbp0 ) single series has multiple dots but I need only one dot in a series so that, I will create multiple series with a single dot in a series.

For example: In our chart having 10 dots means 10 different series.

Comment: @Satyanarayana so as I understand your issue is resolved. Could you accept my answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sebastian I have accepted your answer but need some more information. I need a single dot for series with specific colors, based on the input data, I will construct a series dynamically. 

For example: In our chart having 10 dots means 10 different series with 10 different colors dots.

Comment: Something like is done here? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e4nbp5a3/

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response, I need one final help from you that is, Please provide how to draw the other 3 polygons in the chart with different labels.

Comment: @Satyanarayana as you can notice to render a polygon series as a square to cover some part of the chart you will need to set 4 points in the data array where each point is has defined a [x, y] positions. I hope that this informations help you to figure out the solution. If not - please reproduce your attempt with the particular problem which you are struggling with. My idea to render labels is by using the dataLabels and the formatter callback, see: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ntr1y7vh/

Comment: Thank you a lot Sebastian, 

I need one more help for label alignment for polygon in highcharts
Please find the below link
https://jsfiddle.net/skoormala/nt7jh546/40/

Comment: @Satyanarayana please analyze this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kvom03ep/

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Could you please help on how to place the Lables in scattered chart as below screen shot

Comment: I have raised a question with screen shot pls refer below question         Q. Please refer below new question for more details                                                         Q. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65846404/how-to-add-labels-below-and-above-of-the-highcharts-as-per-below-screenshot