# How to add Labels below and above of the highcharts as per below screenshot

Tags: highcharts, label

please help on how to add laebls in the below scattered charts at all corners but outside polygons
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotations and place them outside plot-area, for example:

```
    annotations: [{
        animation: false,
        labelOptions: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            overflow: 'none',
            borderWidth: 0,
            shape: 'rect',
            style: {
                color: '#000'
            }
        },
        labels: [{
            text: 'some text',
            point: {
                x: 10,
                y: -20
            }
        }, {
            text: 'some text2',
            point: {
                x: 10,
                y: 270
            }
        }]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qm6wd2g5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations